# Fail safe mechanism for Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, architecture, filesystems, system-design

I am working on application that writes to Kafka queue which is read by other application. When I am unable to send message on Kafka due to network or other reason, I need to write messages during Kafka down time to other place e.g Oracle or local file system, so that I don't loose messages generated during down time.Problem with oracle or other DB is it too can go down. Is there any recommendations about how could I achieve fail safe during Kafka down time.

Number of messages generated are approx 20-25 million per day. For messages stored during downtime I am planning to have batch job to re send them to destination application once target application is up again.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push those messages into a cloud based messaging service like [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/). It supports around [3K messages per second](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-messages.html).

There is also a [connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-sqs/current/index.html) that allows you to push back the messages into Kafka directly, with no other headaches.

If you can't export the data out of your local network, then maybe a cluster of RabbitMQ instances may help, although it wouldn't be a plug & play solution.